# Python: Compound functions inside class

Tags: python, django, function, class

I am trying to replicate something similar to model queries in Django.

```
# database.py

class ModelFactory(object):
    def __init__(self, table):
        self.table = table

    def fields(self, *args):
        str_columns = ''
        for count, arg in enumerate(args):
            if count == 0:
                str_columns += arg
            else:
                str_columns += ', %s' % arg
        self.str_columns = str_columns

    def wheres(self, **kwargs):
        str_wheres = ''
        for count, (key, value) in enumerate(kwargs.items()):
            if count == 0:
                str_wheres += 'WHERE %s = %s' % (key, value)
            else:
                str_wheres += ' AND %s = %s' % (key, value)
        self.str_wheres = str_wheres
```

My idea is to use it as follows:

```
from database import ModelFactory

myInstance = ModelFactory('myTable')
myQuery = myInstance.fields('column1', 'column2').wheres(column1 = 5)
```

I am not sure if I need a new class or function inside ModelFactory class that would take the results from 'fields' and 'wheres' to compile a SQL string to query?  Like the following line:

```
cur.execute('SELECT column1, column2 from myTable WHERE column1 = 5')
```

I am also not sure if calling class.function1.function2 is correct? Django has the 'objects' word, e.g. Instance.objects.filter().exclude()

I have tried to change the code base as follows:

```
# database.py

class ModelFactory(object):
    def __init__(self, table):
        self.table = table

    def objects(self):
        def fields(self, **kwargs):
            return self.f(**kwargs)
        def wheres(self, *args):
            return self.w(*args)

    def f(self, *args):
        str_columns = ''
        for count, arg in enumerate(args):
            if count == 0:
                str_columns += arg
            else:
                str_columns += ', %s' % arg
        self.str_columns = str_columns

    def w(self, **kwargs):
        str_wheres = ''
        for count, (key, value) in enumerate(kwargs.items()):
            if count == 0:
                str_wheres += 'WHERE %s = %s' % (key, value)
            else:
                str_wheres += ' AND %s = %s' % (key, value)
        self.str_wheres = str_wheres
```

But when I try the following:

```
from database import ModelFactory

myInstance = ModelFactory('myTable')
myQuery = myInstance.objects.fields('column1', 'column2').wheres(column1 = 5)
```

I get an AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'fields'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to chain object's method calls, you need to return that object from method. i.e. add `return self` to your methods.

So your class declaration probably should be something like the following:

```
class ModelFactory(object):
    def __init__(self, table):
        self.table = table

    def fields(self, *args):
        self.str_columns = ', '.join(args)
        return self

    def wheres(self, **kwargs):
        str_wheres = ' AND '.join('{} = {}'.format(k, v) for k, v in kwargs.items())
        self.str_wheres = 'WHERE {}'.format(str_wheres)
        return self

    def execute(self):
        // ATTN! This code is prone to SQL injection. Do not use!
        cur.execute('SELECT {columns} FROM {table} {wheres}'.format(columns=self.str_columns, table=self.table, wheres=self.wheres))
```

Comment: Thank you - this is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you still have `objects` as a function:

```
def objects(self):
```

Currently, this means that you'll need to call it as a function - your `myQuery` line would need to look something like:

```
myQuery = myInstance.objects().fields(...
```

However, that still wouldn't be enough because `fields` and `wheres` are both only scoped within the `objects` function.

If you want to push down this route, then you will need to create a class that you instantiate inside your model under the attribute `objects` - Django uses `QuerySet` for this. If you check out the [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b3bd3aa07c026239dd39d1a37498dfd0a2f09caf/django/db/models/query.py#L157) you'll see how much magic is required to make something "simple" like `objects` work.

So a simple alternative?

You will have to make a new class similar to `QuerySet` which can provide the `fields` and `wheres` chainable functions - let's call it `WernerfeuerSet`:

```
class WernerfeuerSet:
    def __init__(self, table):
        self.table = table
    def fields(self, **kwargs):
        pass
    def wheres(self, **kwargs):
        pass
```

And now instantiate that within your `ModelFactory` - something like:

```
class ModelFactory:
    def __init__(self, table):
        self.objects = WernerfeuerSet(table)
```

Now your original query should be possible because `objects` is an attribute of the `ModelFactory`, rather than a function:

```
myQuery = myInstance.objects.fields('column1', 'column2').wheres(column1 = 5)
```